# Xcode Source Editor option not displayed in Extensions

Tags: xcode, extension-methods

Is there a way to activate **Xcode Source Editor** option in **System Preferences > Extensions**? For some reason, it's not showing on my Mac *(the last option).*

[image: System preferences extensions screenshot]

Answer (score 32):

If the **Xcode Source Editor** is missing from the left pane (see image above), try one of these solutions before resorting to a reinstallation:

- In the Applications folder, rename Xcode and then change the name back to Xcode, or move Xcode.app out of the Applications folder, then back in, as described by this Stack Overflow answer.
- Move the Xcode app to the Trash and re-install it from the AppStore.

Comment: I changed the name but had to run Xcode under the new name, then change the name back and run Xcode under the old name. Appreciate the bug workaround.

Comment: This issue has been driving me crazy, and your solution worked a dream. Thanks

Comment: Moving Xcode to trash and putting back works, Thanks

Answer (score 4):

I install the Xcode manually that's why not found on Extensions.

**To fix quickly:**

1. Quit Xcode
2. Rename Xcode in the applications folder temporarily with any name.
3. Launch renamed Xcode
4. Quit Xcode
5. Name it back to the old value ("Xcode")
6. Go back to Extention you will find the Xcode

Answer (score 1):

The entry is shown if the system detects that both Xcode and at least one Xcode extension is installed. Yet the code to detect Xcode has a few issues.

If you install Xcode first and don't have an extension, the entry is not shown. If you then install an extension, the system re-checks if Xcode is still installed and if yes, it should add the entry. However, the check code will fail in some situations. E.g. if you renamed `Xcode.app` to something like `Xcode_13.4.app` (as you need to manage different versions of Xcode), the detection code may not find it. It also may not find it if you moved Xcode to a different location outside of `/Applications`. And even if not renamed and still in the default location, the detection code sometimes fails and the exact reason why that happens is unknown (it may have issues with certain ownership, certain file permissions, case-sensitive file systems, etc.)

In all these situations, renaming Xcode causes it to be re-detected by the system and then the system sees that Xcode and at least an extension is installed and the entry appears immediately. No need to reboot or start the renamed Xcode; you rename it, you rename it back, and the entry is there and will stay there (even after deleting all extensions, it stayed on my system).

If you first installed any app with an extension and then Xcode, the problem does never appear as in that case you immediately trigger the rename-fix above, because the moment you install Xcode, the system will always detect it correctly (regardless how the app is named or where it is located or any other issue the scan code might have) and detecting Xcode and knowing there is an extension, the menu entry appears at once. The code that detects Xcode extensions seems to always work correctly.

This is probably one of the issues where the Xcode detection code has not been tested very well by the Apple but since it seems to work for the vast majority of users, Apple sees no reason to further investigate why it would sometimes fail.

Answer (score -3):

It will get activated by default if any plugin are added in Xcode.

You have to download XcodeClangFormat plugin from GitHub and follow the installation steps. Then **Xcode Source Editor** will be visible automatically.

Please refer this [link](https://github.com/mapbox/XcodeClangFormat)