# Xcode Source Editor option not shown in Extensions

Tags: xcode, extension-methods

I checked this previous question and none of the solutions worked. [Xcode Source Editor option not displayed in Extensions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51648536/xcode-source-editor-option-not-displayed-in-extensions)

I originally installed XCode from the app store and have never moved it or renamed it, but there is no XCode Source Editor in System Preferences/Extensions. I was trying to install swiftformat but after installing it did not display in the XCode menu. I see that there is no XCode Source Editor in preferences which seems to be the problem but no idea why it is not there.

[image]